# Error with extended ResultSet

Tags: zend-framework2, resultset

In my project i need a ResultSet that creates my Models, depending on the result data. 
So i extends the \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet and overwrite the `current` method.

```
 /**
 * @return array|\ArrayObject|null
 */
public function current()
{
    $data = $this->dataSource->current();

    if ($this->returnType === self::TYPE_ARRAYOBJECT && is_array($data)) {
        /** @var $ao ArrayObject */
        $ao = $this->getModelClass($data['Type']);
        if ($ao instanceof ArrayObject || method_exists($ao, 'exchangeArray')) {
            $ao->exchangeArray($data);
        }
        return $ao;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

And added this Class as ResultSet to my TableGateway:

```
return new TableGateway('Bookings', $dbAdapter, null, new \MyApp\Db\ResultSet\Entry());
```

It works quite well if i iterate once through the result. But if iterate two or more times through the result the `valid` Method always returns false. 
I already call the `buffer` Method on the ResultSet but it still not works.

If i remove my own class and use the \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet i can iterate multiple time through the result.

Can anyone see the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.
In the first line of my `current` Method i get the current Record as an Array. When i replace this line with a `parent::current` call, the `buffer` works correctly and i can iterate multiple times through my ResultSet.

But i have no explanation for this behavior.